# television with a definite article or without one

Tags: articles

The sentence below comes from Word Smart II: How to Build a More Educated Vocabulary.

> The theory that tiny little men move the pictures around inside **the
>   television** is interesting but implausible; for one thing, you never
>   see anyone putting food in **a TV**.

Why the 1st sentence says 'the television' in contrast to 'a TV' in the last?
Is there any difference between the television and a TV?
To my sense of English grammar, the usage can be reversed as in:

The theory that tiny little men move the pictures around inside **a** television is interesting but implausible; for one thing, you never see anyone putting food in **the** TV.

And it seems OK with me. 
Come to think of it, it seems much better since the second TV refers to the one mentioned previously.

Comment: 'The television' as used here is a typical generic usage; compare 'the tiger is the largest of cats'. 'a TV' is referring to any old set in any old house, a non-definite usage.